# creation of viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the s#arp architecture, ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and NHibernate.

So far I have always created my view models on the fly (in real time after a web request) using, for example, automapper. Sometimes the creation of the view models might be too slow especially if I want to view them in a data grid and use some filtering. I thought I could create my view models once (using dedicated persisted tables/classes) and update them after CUD operations. Does this make sense? Do other people do this? What’s the best practise here –how is it best triggered (e.g. I do not want to recreate all view models after each CUD operation).

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persisting view models into the database doesn't look right to me.
Maybe you could investigate [some other caching strategies](http://www.google.nl/search?q=cache+asp.net+mvc) instead?
For instance [this article on controller output caching](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/outputcachinginmvcapplication02222009222109PM/outputcachinginmvcapplication.aspx).

Comment: It does not sound right to me either. thanks will have a look at this.

Comment: It's actually ain't that bad idea. It's just hard to pull off (the same with output caching). E.g. CQRS architecture explicitly maps denormalized view models (reports) to tables.

Comment: @Arnis There you've got a point ... when considering a report to be a view model, then persisting report data isn't a bad idea. I do doubt if persisting report data (data mining) maps directly to the views the user wants on that data.

Comment: And it might very well be that output caching will turn out to be harder to do then "simple" persistence of the view models (note the quotes around simple). @csetzkorn let us know how you tackled this problem!

Comment: ok I have opted for the viemodel option. I squeeze my 14 tables into two tables. The question is how do I trigger synchronisation when things change in the under lying 14 tables.